# Assigning generator to dictionary directly throws StopIteration

Tags: python, generator

Why this code throws "StopIteration":

```
stub_generator = (x for x in range(5))
stub_dict = {}
stub_dict[next(stub_generator)] = list(stub_generator)
```

and this works?

```
stub_generator = (x for x in range(5))
stub_dict = {}
temp_1 = next(stub_generator)
temp_2 = list(stub_generator)
stub_dict[temp_1] = temp_2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is because of two things:

1. The right-hand side of an assignment statement is evaluated before the left-hand side.
2. Generator objects can be iterated over only once.

---

To explain further, when this code is executed:

```
stub_dict[next(stub_generator)] = list(stub_generator)
```

this part:

```
list(stub_generator)
```

will be evaluated *before* this part:

```
stub_dict[next(stub_generator)]
```

Moreover, placing `stub_generator` in `list` will cause the generator to be iterated over entirely and thus exhausted.  When `next(stub_generator)` is then evaluated afterwards, a `StopIteration` exception is raised because `stub_generator` is now empty.

---

This code however is different:

```
temp_1 = next(stub_generator)
temp_2 = list(stub_generator)
```

It will execute `next(stub_generator)` *before* executing `list(stub_generator)`.  Meaning, `stub_generator` will still have some items in it when it is converted to a list.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [language reference for assignment statements](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements),

```
assignment_stmt ::=  (target_list "=")+ (expression_list | yield_expression)
```

> An assignment statement evaluates the expression list (remember that this can be a single expression or a comma-separated list, the latter yielding a tuple) and assigns the single resulting object to each of the target lists, from left to right.

So, the expression on the right hand side is evaluated first. So, `list(stub_generator)` is executed first and that exhausts the generator and then you are doing `next(stub_generator)` which tries to iterate an already exhausted generator. That is why `StopIteration` is raised.